MassTransit with LavinMQ
Did someone tested LavinMQ with MassTransit ?
On their website they recommend to use the RabbitMQ client nuget package to connect to LavinMQ, so I may be too much optimistic to think it should work ; but may be there's some LavinMQ behaviour not compatible with MassTransit.

I haven't tried it, but it should be easy enough to try using CloudAMQP with the RabbitMQ transport. The only thing that might not work is delayed delivery since that's a RabbitMQ plug-in.

It says it supports Delayed exchanges, so yeah, it probably works for most things.

I just ran the unit tests with it, and it seems to work.

Thanks, I have made some tests on my own, and on the features I use, it seems to work. However on the scenario I test, performance seems to be lower than RabbitMQ.

Like Chris mentions, LavinMQ has some of the RabbitMQ plug-ins like delayed exchanges natively, so that should work fine.
However its worth to mention that LavinMQ does not have quorum queues, and clustering support is not yet available with CloudAMQP. When it is available, it will work differently than it does in RabbitMQ so you won't do the same cluster config.
